# Integrate Chrome with command-line tools

Tags: command-line, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to set up some integration between Chrome, and various command-line tools and build systems that I have. Almost everything that I want to do within Chrome is supported by the extensions API, so I figured I'd make an extension, set up communication between it and my external tools, and go from there.

Unfortunately, I can't find any sane way to get messages in and out of Chrome. The only thing I could find that would plausibly work at all, would be introduce a local web server as a message broker, having the extension connect to it with WebSockets, and then having the command-line utilities do the same. But that's *way* too much complexity - it'd basically mean writing a whole IPC framework.

Is there any reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to let extensions communicate outside Chrome without XHR/WebSockets/SocketAPI or any traditional methods like Image URLs, JavaScript URLs etc.

If you want make an overkill, you could try creating a NPAPI Plugin that writes protocol messages to disk/file (like how Apache WebServer does), and create another standalone Python script/or any other scripting language that tails that. So your API would basically read that file that the NPAPI Extension Plugin creates.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Sounds like the best option would be to submit a patch to Chrome, to plug the API hole. (Probably by extending the HTML5 API with a special permission that lets it use native paths). But I don't think I'm going to pursue this project after all.

Comment: @jimrandomh you should contact the chromium-extensions mailing list, they are pretty good at answering questions quickly regarding future APIs